# error 400 (bad request) con jquery

Tags: java, jquery

amigos haciendo uso del método `.POST` de `jquery` mando unos parametros a un servlet mapeado con `spring`, posterior a ello necesito retornar un valor hacia la vista, para ello transformo el `String` a `JSON` con la libreria `GSON`, pero cuando retorno ese valor me salta ese error 400(bad request), que podre estar haciendo mal? aca les dejo el codigo

Archivo javascript:

```
function sesion(){
        console.log('inicio de envio de parametros a servlet');
        formulario = $('#formBus');
        $.post('ConsultasRms/autenticar.html',formulario.serialize(),function (data,status){
            console.log('entro a función de sesión data: '+data+' estatus: '+status);
            $("#res").html(data);
        }),"JSON";
```

servlet:

```
       @RequestMapping("/autenticar")
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                       @RequestParam("j_username") String user,
                                       @RequestParam("j_password") String pass
    ) throws Exception {

        logger.info("Inicio de metodo login con paramatros usuario: "+user+" y pass: "+pass);
        System.out.println("Inicio de metodo login con paramatros usuario: "+user+" y pass: "+pass);

        String direccion = "index.jsp";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String retorno = gson.toJson(direccion);

       // FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       // request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        if(user.contains("prueba") && pass.contains("1234")){
            System.out.println("autenticado, retorno json: "+retorno);

            return retorno;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno en realidad no soy un experto y tambien estoy empezando a ver Spring pero creo que deberias asiganarle al metodo que intentas usar el metodo por el cual se hara la solicitud es decir :
En el `@RequestMapping(value = "/autenticar")` se  supone deberias tambien indicar el metodo por el cual se ejecutara la peticion creo que es por eso que dice `Bad Request` o error en la peticion seria lago como:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/autenticar", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

espero te ayude en algo.